# Svelte POST input file to api

Tags: javascript, node.js, svelte

So I have a svelte project with a form on my +page, posting to my +server file being handled in a defualt action. When the form posts the file from the input field, it comes through as a blob, `Blob { size: 378533, type: 'image/jpeg' }` what is the usual way you guys would then go ahead and post this to another api the methods I have seen and tried don't seem to be working for me.

just wondering what is wrong with the way I am doing and or what is the better way to POST files uploaded via input fields?

Currently using axios to make the posts.

```
let data = new FormData();
data.append('file', file, file.name);

let config = {
    method: 'POST',
    url:
        '{url}/upload?id=' +
        id +
        '&Authorization=' +
        krill_api_key,
    headers: {
        ...data.getHeaders()
    },
    data: data
};
```

appending the blob directly is returning an error

`node_modules/delayed-stream/lib/delayed_stream.js:33 source.on('error', function() {});`

I have tried to fs readstream as well but this requires a path or buffer url?